# Decode '%' operator on ord strings

Tags: python

I don't get this peice of Python code:

```
cmd=''
cmd+='%02X%02X' % (ord(msg[2]), ord(msg[1]))
```

`msg` is output of `serial.read()` command and is in `bytes` format. I looked up `%` in python doc but couldn't find anything that relates to above.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code?  `ord` only accepts one argument, so I'd've thought it should be `(ord(msg[1]), ord(msg[2]))`.

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: See the [Python docs for using the `%` operator with a string and a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

it's a string formatting technique in Python similar to .format(). It looks like you're putting two 2-digit hex numbers into a string.